# Create a div containing target div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think that this should be easy, but I'm not able to get it working. I want to target a div or other element using jQuery and then dynamically create a div containing the targeted element, for example:

jQuery ('.myclass')

How can I create a div with the background-color attribute set to white that contains 'myclass' element?

Initially I have: `<div class="myclass">Some HTML elements inside</div>`

And after executing the jQuery call i want to have: `<div style="background-color:#fff"><div class="myclass">Some HTML elements inside</div></div>`

I hope that you understand my question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [wrap](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrap#html) function to put a wrapper around the matching elements.  I'd prefer to use a class for the background, but you can assign CSS properties directly as well.

```
$('.myclass').wrap( $('<div></div>').css( 'background-color', '#fff' ) );
```

or

```
$('.myclass').wrap( $('<div></div>').addClass('white-background') );
```

Comment: +1 But ... 'white-background' is not a very semantic class name. Something like 'highlighted' or 'selected' would be better, depending on the reason for the white background. /pedantry

Comment: Agreed - though I didn't have much to work with other than the background needed to be white.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $myDiv = $('<div>').css('background-color','#fff').append( $('.myclass') );
```

You can then write this variable to the DOM as you see fit, or do whatever else you need to do.

Comment: Sorry, i've edited my question, now i hope that you can understand it better, there is more elements with same class into the HTML, there is no only one. I want to have all elements with the given class with a surrounding div with white background.

Comment: The answer by tvanfosson will work better for an in-place edit, if that's what you're trying to achieve.